# Can't use tlmgr following clean installation, tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2021) is older than remote repository (2022)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, tex, ubuntu-22.04, tex-live, tlmgr

I followed the instructions according to https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on Windows 11 WSL.

I cannot get past this error when doing anything with `tlmgr`. Beforehand, I needed to run `tlmgr init-usertree`.

```bash
$ sudo tlmgr install adjustbox
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)

tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2021) is older than remote repository (2022).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

```bash
$ sudo tlmgr update --self
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)

tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2021) is older than remote repository (2022).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

As far as I can tell, I have installed the most up-to-date version:

```bash
$ tex --version
TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2022)
kpathsea version 6.3.4
Copyright 2022 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
```

```bash
$ tlmgr --version
tlmgr revision 63068 (2022-04-18 07:58:07 +0200)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/local/texlive/2022
TeX Live (https://tug.org/texlive) version 2022
```

I have tried removing everything TeX and trying again but receive the same error. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Other resolved threads suggest that the TexLive ftp repository needs to be updated. I'm not sure but I don't think this is the same problem I have.

```bash
$ tlmgr repository list
List of repositories (with tags if set):
        https://mirror2.sandyriver.net/pub/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet (main)
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the silly error, my version of tlmgr was in fact outdated, but only when using `sudo`:

```bash
$ tlmgr --version
tlmgr revision 63068 (2022-04-18 07:58:07 +0200)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/local/texlive/2022
TeX Live (https://tug.org/texlive) version 2022

$ sudo tlmgr --version
tlmgr revision 60693 (2021-10-04 04:24:25 +0200)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/share/texlive
TeX Live (https://tug.org/texlive) version 2021
```

Comment: For me both sudo and normal are the same version